# Simple like-query does not work in MS-Access

Tags: database, ms-access, sql-like

I have a simple `Ms-Access` database with one table named `Student` and it has two columns `ID` and `Name`.

When I the database in Access and enter the query

```
select * from Student where Name like 'J%'
```

in its SQL view, it gives an empty resultset.

But the table has a `Name` called `John`.

I tried with other databases and tables also with `like-queries`, but none works.

Can anyone please tell if there is any special reason for this???

Thank you

**Edit:**

The same query works with c sharp code

Comment: does select * from Student works?

Comment: Yeah, it even works c sharp code...

Comment: It works in C# because you're likely using OLEDB to execute it, which means Jet/ACE is running in ANSI 92 SQL mode, where % is the wildcard operator. Within Access, the default is the legacy (and proprietary) ASNI 89 SQL mode, and that uses * as the wildcard. You can use the % wildcard in ANSI 89 mode if you use the proprietary ALIKE operator.

Comment: @David-W-Fenton: Thanks loads for the comment!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is

```
select * from Student where Name like 'J*'
```

or possibly (because I don't have access handy to check, possibly either will work)

```
select * from Student where Name like "J*"
```

The `*` is the wild card character for MsAccess

Comment: Also--if you have control of the database structure (schema), change the name of `Name`. It's a Reserved Word, and while Access usually lets you get away with that, it doesn't always--and other DBMSs simply won't. The maintenance programmer who comes after you--which may even be yourself--will thank you.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience in the past... yes access syntax has some minor difference that make even simple things a trouble.

I don't remember how but check around a way to make access show the sql from some results you retrieved in a graphical way, there must be some show sql button somewhere.

Once there examine carefully the sql syntax, then test your sql in access' editor. 
So the main idea is let access show you the way!